# No entiendo el por que me sale este error

Tags: mysql, ajax, php7

necesito ayuda, no se por que me sales este error en cuando imprimo por consola un error de tipo [object Object]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi fragmento de código que controla la función ajax

```
function finalizarEvento(registro) {
            $.ajax({
                data: registro,
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../controllers/datoseventos.php?accion=finalizar',
                success: function(msg) {
                    calendar.refetchEvents();
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    var erro = JSON.stringify(error);
                    console.log(erro);
                    alert("Hubo un error al finalizar el evento: " + error);
                }
            })
        };
```

Y estos los datos que le paso:

```
function finalizado() {
            let registro = {
                id: $('#Id').val(),
                titulo: $('#Titulo').val(),
                descripcion: $('#Descripcion').val(),
                inicio: $('#FechaInicio').val() + ' ' + $('#HoraInicio').val(),
                fin: $('#FechaFin').val() + ' ' + $('#HoraFin').val(),
                colorBackground: $('#ColorFondo').val(),
                colorText: $('#ColorTexto').val(),
                estado: 'finalizado'
            }
            return registro;
        }
```

Los datos se tratan en un php aparte y esta es la sentencia que lo trata:

```
case 'finalizar':
        $consulta = "SELECT estado  from eventos WHERE id = '$_POST[id]'";
        $obtenerTitulo = mysqli_query($CRM, $consulta);
        $rows=mysqli_fetch_array($obtenerTitulo);
        $comparador=$rows[0];
        if (strcmp($comparador, "pendiente")==0) {
            $titulo = $_POST['titulo'] . "-finalizado";
            $consulta5 = "UPDATE eventos set titulo='$titulo', estado='$_POST[estado]' WHERE id = '$_POST[id]'";
            $respuesta4 = mysqli_query($CRM, $consulta5);
        echo json_encode($respuesta4);
        }else {
            
        }
    break;
```

P.D. No creo que sea problema de Ajax ya que antes me funcionaba, lo que pasa es que modifique el ultimo trozo de código ya que antes aunque una tarea este finalizada me seguía agregando  "-finalizado" así que trate de arreglar, este el bloque de codigo que tenia antes:

```
case 'finalizar':
        $titulo = $_POST['titulo'] . "-finalizado";
        $consulta5 = "UPDATE eventos set titulo='$titulo', descripcion = '$_POST[descripcion]', inicio = '$_POST[inicio]', fin = '$_POST[fin]', colorText = '$_POST[colorText]', colorBackground='$_POST[colorBackground]', estado='$_POST[estado]' WHERE id = '$_POST[id]'";
        $respuesta4 = mysqli_query($CRM, $consulta5);
        echo json_encode($respuesta4);
        break;
```

Comment: eso no es un error, es un issue y puede ser ignorado.

Comment: Puede ser ignorado, pero es mejor arreglarlo. De todas maneras, Sebas estás en lo cierto que no es problema de ajax. Es problema de tu html :) En algún punto estás usando mal un <label>, y no lo vemos en el código actual.

Comment: Supongo que seria en este label no? 

<!-- <div class="form-row" id="contenEstado"> <label for="">Estado:</label> <select name="estado" id="estadoTarea"> <option value="pendiente" default>pendiente</option> <option value="finalizado" default>finalizado</option> </select> </div> --> 

por que los demás si me funcionan @Benito-B

Comment: pues agrega el HTML amigo, aparenta ser un problema sencillo de solucionar

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ la etiqueta HTML la tengo en mi programa, el problema es en el Label

Comment: Si pones un label ponle el `for="inputDelLabel"`, si no, puedes usar un span o al menos quitar el `for=""`. Aunque no sé si quitando el `for=""` se arreglará el problema, desde luego no tiene sentido tenerlo sin valor. Si no quieres usar el `for` también puedes usar el label como wrapper del input: `<label><input type.../>Texto aquí</label>`.

Comment: @Sebas, hola de nuevo! Veo que tenes varios problemas. 1. `[object Object]` lo obtenes al concatenar un objeto a una cadena (_en tu código es el `alert`. 2. Si te fijas en tu captura dice `responseText: ''`, quiere decir que o esta entrando en el `else` o `json_encode($respuesta4)` es `false` o vacio. 3. Te faltan los encabezados para indicar que la [respuesta es un `JSON`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4064468/3791844).

Comment: @Marcos en mi archivo datoseventos.php, que es donde hago la insersion de datos a la base de datos al principio del todo  tengo  " header('Content-Type: application/json');",  te refieres a esto?, en cuando a lo del [object Object] es un error mío ya que me equivoque al escribir y por lo otro tratare de probarlo con un echo